# Private Variables in Threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, multicore

I'm a starter at using `pthreads` with C in Linux. I need to create and use **private thread variables**.

Let me explain exactly what I need with an example. In the following piece of code I create 4 threads, I would like each of them to create a private variable `foo`, so in total 4 `foo` variables, one for each thread. Each thread should only "see" it's own `foo` variable and not the others. For example, if thread `1` sets `foo = 56` and then calls `doStuff`, `doStuff` should print `56`. If thread `2` sets `foo = 99` and then calls `doStuff`, `doStuff` should print `99`. But if thread `1` calls again `doStuff`, `56` should be printed again.

```
void doStuff()
{
  printf("%d\n", foo); // foo is different depending on each thread
}

void *initThread(void *threadid)
{
  // initalize private thread variable (foo) for this thread
  int foo = something;

  printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!, %d\n", (long) threadid, x);
  doStuff();
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t threads[4];

   long t;
   for (t = 0; t < 4; t++){
     printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
     pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, initThread, (void *) t);
   }

   pthread_exit(NULL); /* support alive threads until they are done */
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this (which is basically the idea of private thread variables) using `pthreads`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the term [Thread Local Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage). Check the documentation for [pthread_get_specific, pthread_get_specific](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_setspecific.html), [pthread_create_key](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_key_create.html) or use the [__thread storage class specifier](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Thread-Local.html).

Another alternative is to have a single global variable and use a mutex, or simply pass foo in as an argument.

Comment: +1 - I've been away from pthreads too long, I completely forgot it provides that as part of the lib.

Comment: Thank you! `__thread` seems the easier way to go. Should you suggest it also for `struct`s?