# Linux Pthread argument

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

This is my code. It's very simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *func(void *arg)
{
    printf("ID=%d\n", *(int*)arg);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t pt[4];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int temp = i;
        pthread_create(&pt[i], NULL, func, (void*)&temp);
    }
    sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it:

`gcc p_test.c -lpthread`

I ran it. It printed `2 2 3 3`. I ran it again. It printed `2 3 3 2`.

My problem is:

Why was `2` or `3` printed twice?

Why didn't it print `1 3 2 0` or any other results?

Comment: Classic undefined behavior. An ordinary data object may not be accessed in one thread while another thread is, or might be, modifying it.

Answer (score 7):

The major problem here is that you're taking the address of the local variable `temp`, and then using that pointer outside the scope of the variable - as soon as you exit one iteration of the loop, your pointer to `temp` becomes invalid and you must not dereference it.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a pointer to a temporary variable into the thread creation function and this temporary goes out of scope at the end of the loop block.  It would seem to me that the temporary address is being reused by the compiler and so that when the threads are executing, they see the same address location.

If you do:

```
int *temp = malloc(sizeof(int));
*temp = i;
pthread_create(&pt[i], NULL, func, (void*)temp);
```

instead, you should see the results you expect.

In this case, the thread function needs to free the `int` after it is printed it to avoid a memory leak.

Also, it's better practice to `pthread_join()` the threads that you're waiting for rather than just `sleep()`ing.

Comment: Although do make sure you free up your allocated memory somewhere (thread exit would be one good place) to avoid the obvious memory leak.

Comment: @Philip Kendall - yes! I just realised i should point that out as well.

Comment: This works, but it would be a whole lot more efficient to just cast the integer argument to `void *`...

Comment: is this 100% safe? you can free the memory before you use it in funk().

Comment: @fhtuft: the idea is to free the memory in the _thread_ function, not in `main` (although I admit the wording is slightly confusing at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

because it prints temp, all threads shares the memory(why temp  is "shared" is explained by TheJuice), so all threads "share"  temp . Use a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) or make temp a private variable. 
[Private Variables in Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9221939/1419494)

Or you can use [phtread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html) like this:

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t pt[4];
    int i;

    for (i =0 ; i < 4; i++)
    {

      pthread_create(&pt[i], NULL, func, (void*)&i);
      pthread_join(pt[i],NULL);

    }

    //sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not quite: this example is significantly different as `temp` is going out of scope. As such, the attempts to dereference it in the threads will be invoking undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *func(void* arg)
{
printf("ID=%d\n", (int)arg);
pthread_exit(NULL);
return 0;
}

int main()
{
pthread_t pt[4];
int i;

for (i =0 ; i < 4; i++)
{

    pthread_create(&pt[i], NULL, func, (void*)i);
    pthread_join(pt[i],NULL);
}



return 0;
```

}