# How to get a pthread name in C

Tags: c, pthreads

Say I create a pthread as `pthread_t lift_3;` and `pthread_create(&lift_1, NULL, lift, share);`. When it goes into `lift()`, how can I get it the function to print the actual name of the thread? Or set a name for the thread?

I have tried using `pthread_self()` to acquire the id, but it instead gives random numbers

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 
void* lift(void* ptr) 
{ 
    printf("thread name = %c\n", pthread_self()); 
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
    return NULL; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    pthread_t lift_1; // declare thread 
    pthread_create(&lift_1, NULL, lift, NULL); 
    pthread_join(lift_1, NULL);  
    return 0; 
}
```

The expected outcome should be `thread name = lift_1`

Comment: `lift_1` is the name of a variable, an internal symbol that doesn't exists at runtime. Thread are identified by ids (roughly numbers). Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091000/how-to-get-thread-id-of-a-pthread-in-linux-c-program and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221939/private-variables-in-threads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the "name of the function that the thread started in".
There is no such thing as "thread name".
When calling `pthread_self`, you get the "id" of the thread, which something like a randomly-generated name.

To simulate the desired behavior in the past, I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <pthread.h> 

// This lines means a variable that is created per-thread
__thread const char* thread_name;

void* lift(void* ptr) 
{ 
    // Paste this line in the beginning of every thread routine.
    thread_name = __FUNCTION__;

    // Note two changes in this line
    printf("thread name = %s\n", thread_name); 
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
    return NULL; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    // Added line
    thread_name = __FUNCTION__;

    pthread_t lift_1; // declare thread 
    pthread_create(&lift_1, NULL, lift, NULL); 
    pthread_join(lift_1, NULL);  
    //Added line
    printf("Original thread name: %s\n", thread_name);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` is a GNU extension kept for (very old) backward compatibility. Use `__func__`.

Comment: That code works fine, but `thread_name` should be inside `pthread_create` as an argument rather than a global variable.

Comment: "There is no such thing as "thread name"" -- on some platforms, there _is_. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html

Comment: good to know! To be fair, `pthread_set_name` is probably implemented using my solution.